# show error message on its own line?

Tags: compilation-mode

I'm using M-x compile to check for compilation errors and it's great. However, I'm wondering if I can get the actual error message to begin on its own line. For some reason the file path shows up as the absolute file path, which is unnecessary IMO (is it possible to change that?).

This makes it so that the error message starts very late in the line and wraps around. I think wrap-around is inevitable with long error messages, but it'd make things much easier to read for me if it would just start on its own line.

[image: emacs error message]

To be clear, I'm wondering if I could change this to something like:

```
cargo build
   Compiling diecast v0.0.1 (file:///home/blaenk/code/rust/diecast/diecast)
/home/blaenk/code/rust/diecast/diecast/src/job/manager.rs:309:53: 309:64
error: type mismatch resolving `<collections::vec_deque::VecDeque<eventual::future::Future<bind::Bind, Box<std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>> as core::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == bind::Bind`:
 expected struct `eventual::future::Future`,
    found struct `bind::Bind` [E0271]
```